# Calculate change in period before in panel data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using panel data, and am trying to create a variable which measures change in my binary dependent variable from one wave to the next, grouped by respondent (ID) and wave.

Here's a simplified version of my data:

```
df <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"),
                  wave = c("1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  binary_dv = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2")
                  )
```

And it should eventually look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"),
                  wave = c("1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  binary_dv = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2"),
                  binary_dv_change = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "-1", "1")
                  )
```

I may also need to put NA values in the first period, like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"),
                  wave = c("1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  binary_dv = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2"),
                  binary_dv_change = c("NA", "1", "0", "NA", "0", "NA", "-1", "1")
                  )
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = group_by(df, id) %>%
               arrange(id, wave2) %>%
               mutate(binary_dv_change = binary_dv - lag(binary_dv)) %>%
               ungroup()
```

But it doesn't work.

It's also worth noting that the panel is unbalanced. And naturally if binary_dv has any NA values, the change value for the next period would have to be NA.

I would also like to be able to specify different periods to measure the change, so not just X - X-1, but change across the whole panel, for instance.

I have tried all the solutions I can find related to this on the site, but none seem to work properly, so would welcome any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your columns are `character`.  Try converting to `numeric` and it should work i.e. `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(diff = c(0, diff(as.integer(binary_dv))))`  If you change the `0` to `NA`, it will be `df3`

Comment: Your mutate will work as intended as well, once you make the two changes @akrun mentions, converting binary_dv to numeric and only group_by id.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! Annoyingly it does need to have some grouping by wave, otherwise it will just calculate from the previous respondent, without considering the wave. So for instance it wouldn't work for this df `df <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5"),
                  wave = c("1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  binary_dv = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2")
                  ) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I eventually found a solution to this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id, wave) %>%
  mutate(change_binary_dv = case_when(
           is.na(binary_dv) == T ~ NA_real_,
           !duplicated(df$id) == T ~ 0,
           TRUE ~ c(0, diff(as.integer(binary_dv)))))
```

Of course, replace

```
TRUE ~ c(0, diff(as.integer(binary_dv)))))
```

with

```
TRUE ~ c(NA_real_, diff(as.integer(binary_dv)))))
```

to get NAs in the first period, as discussed before.